# Upgrade dependencies of dependencies using pip

Tags: python, pip

I have package A, B, and C. Package C is a dependency of package B, and package B is a dependency of package A.

When I pip-install package A with -U, it does not attempt to upgrade package B or C if they are already installed. Is there a way for me to order pip to try updating package requirements recursively?

Comment: Maybe simply upgrade all packages?

Answer (score 4):

```
pip install -U --upgrade-strategy=eager
```

See the docs about upgrade strategies: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-upgrade-strategy

Comment: But wouldn't that reinstall every single requirement, whether an upgrade is needed or not?

Comment: @omermazig Yes. `pip` cannot guess if upgrade is needed or not. Either upgrade strategy is `only-if-needed` for all or `eager` for all. If you have many dependencies but only want to upgrade some you have to upgrade them separately from the rest.